# Summarize hours using 2 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wish to add a summary sheet to a workbook that captures timesheet data.

The timesheet sheets are laid-out like the screenshot below, where each row represents a day, and then a person's total hours worked are distributed across columns C to E, which are identified by a unique combination of seg2 and seg3 codes:

[image]

So, for the first column (C) has a unique combination of 201 & 303, which totals 19.9 hours, then (D) has a unique combination of 201 & 301 which totals 5.9 hours and then (E) has a unique combination of 202 & 303 which totals 11.2 hours.

My summary sheet will look like the screenshot below; where every possible combination of seg2 and seg3 codes are listed:

[image]

What I'm looking for is a formula on the summary sheet against the "January Hours" column that will take the combination of Seg2 and Seg3 codes for its row...

[image]

Then compare that with the range of cells in the timesheet sheet that has the Seg2 and Seg3 codes used:

[image]

Where it finds a match...

[image]

I want it to return the SUM of the range of hours below it...

[image]

...returning the total number of hours for that unique Seg2 and Seg3 combination:

[image]

I'll then drag the fill handle to finish all the formulas for the Summary sheet's "January Hours" column.

I've managed to do this using a single seg code using `SUMPRODUCT`, but have not yet figured out how to do it for 2 criteria (i.e. 2 seg codes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By leaving the row parameter of the INDEX function empty, you can lookup an entire column. See the below formula and enter with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=SUM(INDEX($C$4:$E$8,,MATCH($G2,IF($H2=$C$2:$E$2,$C$1:$E$1),0)))
```

[image]

Please note that this formula sums up all the values in the table as suggested in your example, and not just the values with a date of 1/1/2015.

Answer (score 1):

INDEX/MATCH can handle a 2-way match -- is it necessary to "re-sum" the hours? If the Seg2/Seg3 Totals from the time sheets are always in the same place, this will look up the total hours:

=INDEX(Timesheet!$C$2:$E$10,9,MATCH($A2&$B2,Timesheet!$C$2:$E$2&$C$3:$C$3,0))

Edit: forgot to note this is an array formula

Comment: This works too, I just went with @rwilson as the real version of the timesheet doesn't ultimately have the totals row at the bottom to use (the timesheet is externally created and I can't change it unfortunately). Thanks for this though.

Comment: thanks for the feedback :) (plus I learned INDEX can return an array)